# How to Pass ID and Status through anger tag using codIgniter4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am trying to update appointment status from waiting to approval Onclick button using CodeIgniter 4.
How to pass both ID and status through anger tag using CodeIgniter 4 and how to retrive the data from the URL to controller  function update_status.

Answer (score 0):

define custom attrbute for a tag

```
$id=1;
$status=true;
<a id="x" href="#" data-id="<?=$id;?>"  data-stastus="<?= $status;?>">clike me</a>
```

use javescript or jquery or angular to call custom attrbute
for exmple juery

```
var id=$('x').atrr('data-id');
```